# Получить 2 параметра ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть , к примеру, страница php

```
echo "результат1";
echo "результат2";
```

и запрос ajax к ней

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editcodeoutput.php",
            data:"post="+id,
            success: function(result) { 

              $('#note').val(result);


            }
          });
```

В данной ситуации оба результата будут посланы в значение `#note`, а как, например, мне первый `echo` в одно поле вставить,а второй во второе.

Что бы получить подобие такого

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "editcodeoutput.php",
                data:"post="+id,
                success: function(result) { 

                  $('#note').val(result);
                  $('#enot').val(result2);

                }
              });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте json.

```
echo json_encode(array('result1'=>'Результат 1', 'result2'=>'Результат 2'));
```

В $.ajax добавьте `dataType: 'json'`, тогда на входе у success будет уже десериализованный json. Функцией error можно отловить неверный json.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "editcodeoutput.php",
    data:"post="+id,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        $('#note').val(data.result1);
        $('#enot').val(data.result2);
    }
});
```